# How can I override a function from AbstractModel class? In Odoo 9

Tags: inheritance, odoo, overriding, odoo-9

I want to override the **message_post** function from **class MailThread**
 (models.AbstractModel).
 
Until now, I create a new addon which inherits from a model and then, I override the wanted function and it worked fine.

I don't know why, but it doesn't work doing it with MailThread. Maybe it is because is an AbstractModel?

The program is executing the original code and not this one:

```py
class MailThread(models.AbstractModel):
  _inherit = ['mail.thread']

  @api.multi
  @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
  def message_post(self, body='', subject=None, message_type='notification',
             subtype=None, parent_id=False, attachments=None,
             content_subtype='html', **kwargs):
    ... (my stuff) ...
    return new_message
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this will help other guys.
The code above has no problem.
The only thing that needs to do is to add "mail" as a dependency in current module's **manifest**.py.